# How to unzip a .gz archive with one single file inside in node.js (Lambda Function on Amazon Webservices)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, gzip

I am pretty new to JavaScript, AWS-Lambda and node.js (so basically I am new to all of these technologies), but I also have some development experience in Java.

I am trying to unzip / decompress a .gz file in a node.js application / function which is hosted in AWS Lambda as Lambda function. But I cannot figure out how to decompress the file. Here is my code:

```
var async = require('async');
var JSZip  = require('jszip');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
   console.log("AWS Function Start!");

    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));  

    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            // Download the gz file from S3 into a buffer and pass the buffer to next function
            s3.getObject({
                    Bucket: srcBucket,
                    Key: srcKey
                },
                next);
            },

        function secondFunction(response, next) {
            console.log("scondFunction")

            var zip = new JSZip(response.body);
             async.forEach(zip.files, function (zippedFile) {

            var f = zippedFile;
            console.log(f.name);
             });

        }], function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("error");
            } else {
                console.log("success");
            }

            callback(null, "message");
        }
    );

};
```

So I am loading an aws object (the .gz archive file) from Amazon S3 first. That works fine and I have the file (as bytestream) I guess. So I think, that the Lambda package I uploaded is OK, since I used npm to install the required libs. But when the function is triggered in AWS Lambda, I get the following error message:

```
2017-06-11T15:55:18.612Z    ef56fbfe-4ebd-11e7-ad06-05089152cc1f    Error: The constructor with parameters has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide.
at Object.JSZip (/var/task/node_modules/jszip/lib/index.js:14:15)
at secondFunction (/var/task/AwsHtwFunction.js:28:14)
at nextTask (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5273:14)
at Response.next (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5280:9)
at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:360:18)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
```

I know, what it means, but I can`t figure out how to do it properly. Is it even the right library I am using?

Hope that somebody can help. If needed, I will provide any further information, that is required in order to solve my issue.

Thanks a lot!!!

**EDIT 2017.06.14 19:09**:
content of package.json file inside module jzip:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "jzip",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "jzip",
        "name": "jzip",
        "rawSpec": "",
        "spec": "latest",
        "type": "tag"
      },
      "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AWS\\test"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "jzip@latest",
  "_id": "jzip@1.0.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/jzip",
  "_nodeVersion": "4.5.0",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/jzip-1.0.0.tgz_1480154340888_0.22487609554082155"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "clarketm",
    "email": "travis.m.clarke@gmail.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "3.10.6",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "jzip",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "jzip",
    "name": "jzip",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "spec": "latest",
    "type": "tag"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jzip/-/jzip-1.0.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "78e15fc5cfd3387315900473d7efe85bc52d6f8c",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "jzip",
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\AWS\\test",
  "author": {
    "name": "clarketm"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/clarketm/jszip/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "78e15fc5cfd3387315900473d7efe85bc52d6f8c",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jzip/-/jzip-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "gitHead": "ca81b063424ea31f19b531c7bc9136dc19a75ea1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/clarketm/jszip#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "jszip"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "jzip.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "clarketm",
      "email": "travis.m.clarke@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": "jzip",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/clarketm/jszip.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What version of jszip do you have now?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! According to my package.json file npm installed version 1.0.0 of jzip.

Comment: This appears to be fairly unrelated to aws-lambda. It looks like you just need to take the time to look at the jszip API and change your code to use it properly. The error message is specifically telling you not to use the constructor that takes arguments. Are you copying code from an old example or something? It should be trivial to look at the examples in the official API docs to understand how to use this library: http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be looping through the files in the response body and sending each one to the unzip library, instead of trying to unzip the entire response body?

Comment: I was not sure about looping, but as far as I know a gz archive only can contain one single file and not several files. In case you want to have multiple files in one gz archive you have to create a tar ball first.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to figure out how to do it in (node)JS and AWS Lambda also supports Java, I managed to accomplish it by using Java:

```
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(myInputStream);
InputStreamReader reader_gz = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader_gz); 

while ((readedLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     //It is a text file, so I can read it line per line
     //do sth. with line...
}
```